# Objective-C - Element-wise addition (and division) of two matrices with Accelerate.framwork

Tags: ios, objective-c, matrix, accelerate-framework

I have two matricies (of type `float *`), so I guess they can be viewed as arrays.

I need to do an element-wise addition of the two matrices, and I would like to increase performance as much as possible. This will be for an iOS app, so I would like to see if the `Accelerate.framework` has such a function to do this.

The documentation for `Accelerate.framework` is a bit difficult to understand though. There are a bunch of functions with the word `add` in them, but I have no idea which or how they work.

Has anyone had to do this before? Can you point me in the correct direction?

NOTE: I will also need to do the same this for division (i.e., element-wise division); and I'd like to also use `Accelerate.framework` if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your matrices can be viewed as arrays (are contiguous in memory), the functions you’re looking for are `vDSP_vadd` and `vDSP_vdiv`.

Comment: Great! I was looking at the BLAS docs, and it was so much more confusing than vDSP. Thanks again! I'll accept as soon as SO allows me too.